Reflections on a PCB
We have designed a PCB which consists 6 RF chains. In one single chain it consists of limiter + LNA + SPDT.
We are getting good S parameters (gain, return loss.) The only issue is that we have observed reflections at the ports.
We have crosschecked whether it is due to poor impedance match.  Everything is good with respect to impedance matching and grounding.

Can you show your measurements regarding impedance matching?

How much reflected power are you seeing, and how much is acceptable? How closely are your impedances matched? Without qualifying these, the nature of the problem is unclear. What exactly are you looking for help with? Please edit your question to include these and any other details.

Insufficient decoupling near high-speed components like the LNA or limiter can lead to power supply noise coupling into the signal path, leading to reflections.
